# php - New Instagram API

Tags: php, api, token, instagram-api

I would like to implement Instagram for a Wordpress plugin.
This plugin will allow user to display instagram images with comments, likes, etc... I would like to use different source like user, tags, etc... There will be no interaction with like, comment system. It's just a plugin to display an instagram grid.

However I don't understand what is the right way to use the new API. On the instagram developer guide it's mentioned that the new API will be limited for the number of connections, etc... I don't know if it can concern my case for the plugin I want to develop.

To sum up, does the access token is enough to do what I want or do I need to use the API like this wrapper class with 'api Key', 'api Secret', 'api Callback'. It seems that information can be retrieve in different way but I don't understand what I should use. Or do I need to create an APP?

Maybe these questions can seem stupid but I'm not fluent in English and the developer guide of instagram is just not clear for me about the way I should use instagram for authentication/connection with any user.
I hope someone can guide me a little bit.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by "does the access token is enough to do what I want or do I need to use the API like this wrapper class with 'api Key', 'api Secret', 'api Callback' "?  
Because access token is generated from 'api key' and 'api secret', so automatically, you need those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways you can approach this problem.

1) The plugin requires each user to register their own app with Instagram.

This means each user who installs the plugin would need to go through the [app review process](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/). Plus you would need to provide away for the users to supply their `client_id`, `client_secret` and a callback. Essentially you write the code to make everything work but the complexity of configuring the OAuth flow is still up to your users.

2) You register your plugin as an app with Instagram and make requests on your users behalf.

This is the intent of OAuth and Instagrams new API updates. This will also push all the complexity to you the plugin author. Since this is open code you will need to figure out away to keep your `client_secret` secure. One solution could be running a service for your plugin that handles the OAuth flow. You might also have API limit concerns depending upon your plugin adoption and usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does an app is mandatory with the new instagram api? Can I still get content from instagram (recent media, hashtag media) just with the access_token from the user without using an app? What is the difference between the app and the api just using access token?

Comment: In order to receive an `access_token` you have to go through the [OAuth flow](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) which will require an app with it's `cilent_id` and `client_secret`. Once you have the `access_token` you can use any api endpoint that uses the scopes you requested from the user during authentication.

The "app" simple represents you as a developer so Instagram can track and throttle your usage if they detect api abuse.

Comment: Ok thank for the answer. So, whatever the method the access token will be limited for endpoint request. I have created an app to automatically get access_token from users but I'm still wainting for the review in order to use it. In sandbox mode the access token generated (even for registered user in sandbox mode) do not have any permission for all scopes...

Comment: Just remember the access_token is not given automatically. You need to create an OAuth flow for your users to be granted one. And during that OAuth flow you need to specify the scopes you need. For example this is what my OAuth flow request url looks like; https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?`client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&scope=basic%20public_content`. As you can see I'm request the `basic` and `public_content` scopes.

Comment: Also in case you missed it like I did, after "registering your client" you need to start a second process to "submit for review". See the section "How to Submit for Permissions Review" found here; https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already did that. How many times did it take in order to be approved?

Comment: Starting my second submission. Unfortunately the rejection reason seemed programmatic, just pointed to valid use cases. No details on specific issues or what needs to be changed.

Comment: My second submission was approved. I made sure to identify how my app meet the [valid use cases](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/#what-are-the-valid-use-cases).